# gzip Compression not working on custom REST API

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

We have a custom REST API that doesn't seem to support gzip compression.

```
curl https://mobileteamdeploycommunity.force.com/taroworks/services/data/v33.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -v
```

Which uses the Salesforce API seems to work fine and compresses that data. But

```
curl https://mobileteamdeploycommunity.force.com/taroworks/services/apexrest/performance/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'  -v &> performance_with_gzip
```

Which uses our custom REST API doesn't compress and we get the JSON result uncompressed.

Is there a way to make compression work in the second case?

Comment: One oddity in the documentation for [Force.com REST API Developer's Guide - Using Compression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compression.htm) "The REST API **is not required to compress the response even if you have specified Accept-Encoding, but it normally does**. If the REST API compresses the response, it also specifies a Content-Encoding header." Is there something odd about what the REST service is returning that might prevent compression?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the docs. Wish they said under what circumstances Salesforce compresses. The response is just straight JSON that could benefit quite a bit from compression. Can't think of a reason why it would be compressed.

Comment: What headers do you see in the response? I did a quick HTTP GET test against a very basic `@RestResource` that just returns a short string. It came back with Content-Encoding: gzip, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8. So it would appear to be compressed.

Comment: Interesting. So the Salesforce REST returns: < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Content-Encoding: gzip
 Vary: Accept-Encoding.    Our REST calls return: Content-Type: application/octetstream.  I suspect that your string wasn't compressed because it was too short. Compression is not worthwhile if the string is short. But I need to see if I can replicate getting Content-Encoding: gzip.

Comment: I was using Postman in Chrome to test with. Looking at the Network tab in the developer tools I noticed it would send the Accept-Encoding header regardless. Your 'Content-Type: application/octetstream' looks odd to me. I wouldn't have expected the Content-Type to change based on the compression. You wouldn't be returning a Blob by any chance?

Comment: Not exactly sure what's triggering this on our side (not my code :-)), but my test seems to indicate that it's something that we're doing, rather than a salesforce issue. @DanielBallinger thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Created a simple test with the following code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/testRest/*')
global with sharing class TestRest {

@HttpGet
global static List<sObject> doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    List<sObject> result = [SELECT id, ownerId, name from report];
    return result;
  }

}
```

Ran the curl command

> curl https://na16.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/testRest -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -v > performance_with_gz ; cat performance_with_gz

Where xxxxxx is the token (see resources on how to get it) and the result headers were:
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2015 21:23:41 GMT
    < Set-Cookie: BrowserId=vOR1P_eXQxSIXNSlB05oxA;Path=/;  Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Mon, 15-Jun-2015 21:23:41 GMT
    < Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    < Content-Encoding: gzip
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked

and the content was indeed gzip encoded.

So Salesforce does indeed gzip compress custom REST APIs and it looks like the issue is on our side.

Resources:

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/07/try-any-salesforce-api-quickly-with.html
http://www.oyecode.com/2014/08/start-building-your-own-rest-api-in.html
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

Comment: The issue was that we were returning void from doGet() and setting the data in RestContext.response.responseBody, but didn't do response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  Since the responseBody is a blob, As Daniel correctly guessed above,  it returns Content-Type: application/octetstream.