# Apex Rest Web Service not sending compressed gzip response

Tags: json, apexrest

I have an Apex Rest web service that is being called from a Java client and I want the response to be in GZIP format.

Here is part of my code where from I am adding headers in the PATCH request from Java:

```
StringEntity messageEntity = new StringEntity(parentJSONObj.toString(), ContentType.create("application/json"));

HttpPatch httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords = new HttpPatch(instanceURL + "/services/apexrest/SyncSFBusinessPartnerComp/");
httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords.setEntity(messageEntity);
```

However when I get back the response, the header **Content-Encoding: gzip isn't there in the Response**. I am checking the headers thus:

```
CloseableHttpResponse closeableresponse = httpclient.execute(httpPatchToSendUpdatedRecords);
for(Header header: closeableresponse.getAllHeaders()) {
    System.out.println("Header " + header.getName() + ":" + header.getValue());
}
```

So that means my response is not compressed, am I correct?

The second line here gives exception:

```
HttpEntity entity = closeableresponse.getEntity();
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);//Gives exception java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
```

Any ideas what I am missing? Do I have to write additional code on the server side to compress the response? This is what I am returning from server side:

```
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(gen.getAsString());
```

where gen is a JSONGenerator object.

Edit:

I have found the cause of the ZipException, it was because I was forcefully trying to set the response header from the server in this way:
    RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
On removing this line there are not more exceptions. All the same, the Content-Encoding header is still not there...

Here are my response headers:

> Header Date:Tue, 10 Apr 2018 10:06:33 GMT
>   Header Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>   Header X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
>   Header X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
>   Header Content-Security-Policy:upgrade-insecure-requests
>   Header X-Robots-Tag:none
>   Header Cache-Control:no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
>   Header Set-Cookie:BrowserId=Tg2r62kASpabEtQUVeSrXg;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 09-Jun-2018 10:06:33 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
>   Header Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>   Header Content-Type:application/json
>   Header Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Answer (score 2):

Found this oddity in the Docs (my emphasis): [Source - Using Compression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compression.htm)

> To use compression, include the HTTP header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` or `Accept-Encoding: deflate` in a request. The REST API compresses the response if the client properly specifies this header. The response includes the header `Content-Encoding: gzip` or `Accept-Encoding: deflate`. You can also compress any request by including a `Content-Encoding: gzip` or `Content-Encoding: deflate` header.
>
> ## Response Compression
>
> The REST API can optionally compress responses. Responses are compressed only if the client sends an Accept-Encoding header. **The REST API is not required to compress the response even if you have specified Accept-Encoding, but it normally does.** If the REST API compresses the response, it also specifies a Content-Encoding header.

It would appear that while they probably will send back a response compressed as you have requested they don't have to. It seems odd, and there is no further clarification provided in the docs on whey they might bypass the compression.

I suspect you will need to check the response headers before attempting to decompress it.

---

I've come across this before in [gzip Compression not working on custom REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/72355/102).

In that case the issue was around sending the blob back directly in the response without explicitly setting the response content type.

Try something like:

```
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(gen.getAsString());
RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

It might help to be explicit so the Salesforce knows what is going back and that it can be compressed.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately I had already seen that post and accordingly explicitly set the Content-Type header.. but no luck. I will be going by the conditional decompression as suggested by you.