# Is it possible to create a REST API in salesforce that returns zip file

Tags: apex, rest-api, zip

I want to expose a REST API to the other website. The REST API in salesforce basically needs to query on Opportunity data as well as Files related to Opportunity, zip it and return it.

**Questions:**

Is it possible to return zip file via REST API?

Are there any limitations to the above logic?

Thanks

Comment: Zip/unzip is a struggle in Apex as no API is exposed and Apex doesn’t include direct handling for bytes. Having said that, Google because there is at least one Apex implementation though likely to be slow so only good for small amounts of data. Why not just return JSON?

Comment: ok so if I choose the JSON path, I can embed opportunities data as well as files inside it and return that list? After receiving the JSON list by third-party, the data can easily be converted into actual image/pdf document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to return zip file via REST API?

*Possible*, yes, *wise*, no. Neither Apex nor the Lightning Platform is especially well-suited to this kind of binary file manipulation, but some very clever people have built a [library](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex) to manage ZIP files in Apex. (Disclaimer: I have not used it myself).

> Are there any limitations to the above logic?

Yes. All of the ordinary governor limits apply. In this case, I suspect Heap Size may be the first one to bite you, since the string manipulation the library above must make in order to interact with the binary file content and perform compression is not memory-efficient. Or fast.

I would encourage instead returning from the API a list of `ContentVersion` Ids and having the remote system send a separate request to the native Salesforce REST API to retrieve the body of each, or implementing this API endpoint on a middleware platform that has fewer governor-style constraints.

Comment: ok so if I go for the second option, what would be the return type of REST API method if I am returning opportunities data and contentversion Ids? Is there any sample code for that?

Comment: @Anonymous Presumably it would be a JSON response body that your application would define. Your use case is quite specific and I am not aware of any sample code that bears on it more closely than what you will find on Trailhead.

Comment: I was able to retrieve Salesforce data and files links/ids. How do I make a second call to retrieve the actual file content?

Answer (score 4):

If the client requests it, the response can be compressed using standard HTTP/1.1 semantics. From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compression.htm):

> To use compression, include the HTTP header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` or
>   `Accept-Encoding: deflate` in a request. The REST API compresses the
>   response if the client properly specifies this header.

Also see this Q&A for additional info: [gzip Compression not working on custom REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72355/gzip-compression-not-working-on-custom-rest-api)